# Trying to click an element on a webpage using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to write a script to fill out a form but I'm struggling to click the free sim link, I have tried using multiple different identifiers but can't seem to get any to work. Greatly appreciate any help! Thank you

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://mobile.lebara.com/gb/en/free-sim")

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

cookie = driver.find_element_by_id("onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
freesim = driver.find_element_by_class_name("product-item payAsYouGoProductListerItem clickable")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(cookie).perform()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
actions.click(freesim).perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to deal with "accept cookies" banner (click on it, you don't need actions, only EC then click)
2. replace all implicit waits in your code with expected_conditions

(In case all these recommendations don't work for you have to update your question with code and selenium exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

You need to click "Accept cookies" or execute JS code to hide "Your cookies" overlay and then search for link.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

cookie = driver.find_element_by_id("onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
cookie.click()
freesim = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Free Sim")
freesim.click()
```

Note that you're trying to pass multiple class names to `find_element_by_class_name` (you need to pass one only) and call `driver.implicitly_wait(5)` several times (you might do this only once)

Answer (score 0):

Your class name contains spaces and thus are actually multiple class names. You can make a CSS selector by prefixing each class name with a dot.

```
CSS Selector ->> ".product-item.payAsYouGoProductListerItem.clickable"
```

You also have to wait until the element is clickable before you click. Add this to/change this in your code. The rest of your code works fine.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

....
....
....

freesim = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".product-item.payAsYouGoProductListerItem.clickable")))
freesim.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element <kbd>Free Sim</kbd> you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='free-sim-direct']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://mobile.lebara.com/gb/en/free-sim")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='free-sim-direct']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://mobile.lebara.com/gb/en/free-sim")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='free-sim-direct']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```